# qt-linguist- Merging .ts files

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

I am translating the GUI of **QGIS** desktop software.
The current developing version is on transifex platform from which it can be extracted the corresponding `.ts` file.

the older versions of **QGIS** are archived on github.

I'd like to insert the missing strings translated in the newer version in the older version. Also some strings have been corrected in the new version and I'd like to replace them in the older.

I used lconvert in this form:

```
lconvert -i 2.18.ts 2.99.ts -o total.ts
```

But `QT Linguist` warns that in `total.ts` there are duplicated strings.

Is it possible to insert in the older version (2.18) only the strings that are the same from the newer (2.99)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran three years ago with the ts-tools from Qt4 into the same problem.
The manual says that the call of lconvert (just like you laid it out) will merge the content (means: the translations from two sources) into a new file. And I expected "merge" to work like "make a superset out of both". But it did not.

I wrote myself a bash-script to merge it in a way I want to. Will try to find the file this evening.
(I know, right now the answer is - beside confirming the error - not helpful.)

Comment: Did you find your bash script?